# applying several functions in transform in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, transformation

After a `groupby`, when using `agg`, if a dict of `columns:functions` is passed, the functions will be applied in the corresponding columns. Nevertheless this syntax doesn't work with `transform`. Is there another way to apply several functions in `transform`?

Let's give an example:

```
import pandas as pd
df_test = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[1,20,30],[2,30,50],[1,2,33],[2,4,50]],columns = ['a','b','c'])
Out[1]:
    a   b   c
0   1   2   3
1   1   20  30
2   2   30  50
3   1   2   33
4   2   4   50

def my_fct1(series):
    return series.mean()

def my_fct2(series):
    return series.std()

df_test.groupby('a').agg({'b':my_fct1,'c':my_fct2})

Out[2]:
    c   b
a       
1   16.522712   8
2   0.000000    17
```

The previous example shows how to apply different function to different columns in `agg`, but if we want to transform the columns without aggregating them, `agg` can't be used anymore. Therefore:

```
df_test.groupby('a').transform({'b':np.cumsum,'c':np.cumprod})
Out[3]:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

How can we perform such an action with the following expected output:

```
    a   b   c
0   1   2   3
1   1   22  90
2   2   30  50
3   1   24  2970
4   2   34  2500
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think now (pandas 0.20.2) function [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) is not implemented with `dict` - columns names with functions like `agg`.

If functions return `Series` with same lenght:

```
df1 = df_test.set_index('a').groupby('a').agg({'b':np.cumsum,'c':np.cumprod}).reset_index()
print (df1)
   a     c   b
0  1     3   2
1  1    90  22
2  2    50  30
3  1  2970  24
4  2  2500  34
```

But if aggreagte different length need [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df2 = df_test[['a']].join(df_test.groupby('a').agg({'b':my_fct1,'c':my_fct2}), on='a')
print (df2)
   a          c   b
0  1  16.522712   8
1  1  16.522712   8
2  2   0.000000  17
3  1  16.522712   8
4  2   0.000000  17
```

Answer (score 7):

You can still use a dict but with a bit of hack:

```
df_test.groupby('a').transform(lambda x: {'b': x.cumsum(), 'c': x.cumprod()}[x.name])
Out[427]: 
    b     c
0   2     3
1  22    90
2  30    50
3  24  2970
4  34  2500
```

If you need to keep column a, you can do:

```
df_test.set_index('a')\
       .groupby('a')\
       .transform(lambda x: {'b': x.cumsum(), 'c': x.cumprod()}[x.name])\
       .reset_index()
Out[429]: 
   a   b     c
0  1   2     3
1  1  22    90
2  2  30    50
3  1  24  2970
4  2  34  2500
```

Another way is to use an if else to check column names:

```
df_test.set_index('a')\
       .groupby('a')\
       .transform(lambda x: x.cumsum() if x.name=='b' else x.cumprod())\
       .reset_index()
```

Comment: What would be solution in case of the groupby contains more than one column?

Answer (score 3):

With the updates to Pandas, you can use the `assign` method, along with `transform` to either append new columns, or replace existing columns with new values :

```
grouper = df_test.groupby("a")

df_test.assign(b=grouper["b"].transform("cumsum"), 
               c=grouper["c"].transform("cumprod"))

    a   b   c
0   1   2   3
1   1   22  90
2   2   30  50
3   1   24  2970
4   2   34  2500
```