# Panda equivalent of R's dplyr group_by+mutate

Tags: python, r, pandas, dplyr

I am trying to find a way to replicate `R's dplyr` combintaion of `group_by` and `mutate` in pandas using chaining.

In **R** I can:

```
library('nycflights13')
library('dplyr')
df = flights

df = df %>%
  group_by(origin, day) %>%
  mutate(air_time_avg = mean(air_time, na.rm= TRUE),
         air_time_max = max(air_time, na.rm= TRUE),
         air_time_min = min(air_time, na.rm= TRUE),
         air_time_std = sd(air_time, na.rm= TRUE))
```

In **python**, the best I could find is the following, where I have to spell out the groupby every time and will not be able to use this in part of large chaining operation:

```
import pandas as pd
from nycflights13 import flights
df['mean_airtime'] = df.groupby(['origin','day'], as_index=True)['air_time'].transform('mean')
df['min_airtime'] = df.groupby(['origin','day'], as_index=True)['air_time'].transform('min')
df['max_airtime'] = df.groupby(['origin','day'], as_index=True)['air_time'].transform('max')
df['std_airtime'] = df.groupby(['origin','day'], as_index=True)['air_time'].transform('std')
```

Interestingly, for `R's summarise`, there is a neat panda equivalent using `NamedAgg`:

```
df.groupby(['origin','day'])\
  .agg(
    airtime_avg=pd.NamedAgg(column='air_time',aggfunc='mean'),
    airtime_max=pd.NamedAgg(column='air_time',aggfunc='max'),
    airtime_min=pd.NamedAgg(column='air_time',aggfunc='min'),
    airtime_std=pd.NamedAgg(column='air_time',aggfunc='std'))\
  .reset_index()
```

Is there any way to get something similar with transform?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44677103/applying-several-functions-in-transform-in-pandas) post might contain the answer you need.